# Put date (w/o time!) in printout header/footer in Firefox

Tags: firefox, javascript

Using `&D` I can put date and time in the bottom right corner of every Firefox print-out (File > Page Setup > Margins & Header/Footer > Right: > Custom > `&D` ).

Can I put only the date?

Comment: It's possible, please check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Getting_Started/XUL_user_interfaces

Comment: @karthikrangaraj: sorry, I don't know how to make use of the information on the page you suggest. Could you help?